# Iterate through multiple dataframes and perform calculation based on specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

I have several data frames that have months as the columns, and contain integer values. I am posting 2 for this example.

```
df1 =     
             June 2016       July 2016
Flavor
Vanilla      17.0            23.0
Chocolate    7.0             12.0
Strawberry   11.0            14.0

df2 =        
             June 2016       July 2016
Flavor
Vanilla      9.0            19.0
Chocolate    10.0           3.0
```

How can I iterate through each dataframe and perform a calculation dependent on the row and column name of the dataframe when they have to match? For example, I want to calculate the average for Vanilla for July, which would be (23 + 19)/2. If a `Flavor` also does not exist in a data frame, then I would also like to assign a constant value (say 15 in this example) per month in that data frame. Would I append the data frames together then apply `.mean()`?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for any abruptness, I am currently on the go, traveling.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, wide datasets again! We meet again.

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby` with columns

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],1).fillna(15).groupby(level=0,axis=1).mean()
Out[408]: 
            July2016  June2016
Chocolate        7.5       8.5
Strawberry      14.5      13.0
Vanilla         21.0      13.0
```

Comment: Nice! That's a lot better than what I had!

Answer (score 0):

Consider directly  vectorize as you can run arithmetic operations across similar structured dataframes:

```
(df1 + df2.reindex(labels=df1.index.values, fill_value=15)) / 2

#             June 2016  July 2016
# Flavor                          
# Vanilla          13.0       21.0
# Chocolate         8.5        7.5
# Strawberry       13.0       14.5
```

And for many dataframes in a list, consider `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

df_list = [df1, df2]
new_df_list = [d.reindex(labels=df1.index.values, fill_value=15) for d in df_list]

reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, new_df_list) / len(new_df_list)

#             June 2016  July 2016
# Flavor                          
# Vanilla          13.0       21.0
# Chocolate         8.5        7.5
# Strawberry       13.0       14.5
```

Data

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = '''             
Flavor      "June 2016"       "July 2016"
Vanilla      17.0            23.0
Chocolate    7.0             12.0
Strawberry   11.0            14.0'''

df1 = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", index_col=0)


txt = '''             
Flavor      "June 2016"       "July 2016"
Vanilla      9.0            19.0
Chocolate    10.0           3.0'''

df2 = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", index_col=0)
```